# keras CNN 1-D -> Why are all predicted classes returning equal?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, output, conv-neural-network

I coded a CNN 1-D, but when executing the `model.predict_classes(X)` command all returned classes are the same. The return example is in the following screen. Why are all predicted classes returning equal? I've already changed the input to different ones, and the result remains the same.

```python
model = ke.models.Sequential() 
nbfeatures=5
model.add(Conv1D(filters=2,kernel_size=2,input_shape=(nbfeatures, 1),activation = 'relu')) 
model.add(Conv1D(filters=2,kernel_size=2)) 
model.add( MaxPool1D(pool_size=2))
model.add( Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add( Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, nesterov=True, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])

# get some data
#X = np.expand_dims(np.random.randn(1000, 5), axis=2)
X = np.expand_dims([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]], axis=2)
#y = [np.random.randint(0,2) for p in range(0,10)]
y=[[1],[0],[1],[1],[1],[0],[1],[1],[1],[1]]
y=np.array(y)
y = np.reshape(np.array(y), (y.shape[0],1))

# fit model
model.fit(X, y,batch_size=5, epochs=3, verbose=1)
predictions = model.predict(X)
Y_predict = model.predict_classes(X)
```

[screen - output CNN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27yv7.png)

Answer (score 1):

After experimenting with this, I believe the issue is due to the small number of training examples and the fact that all of the examples of each of your 2 classes are identical. As Matias stated, the imbalance of the training classes isn't ideal either. But, really, the identical examples I think cause the most problems, as the learning pathways for tweaking the weights are the same for all examples of each class.

So, with so few training examples, you need to either increase the number of iterations or increase the number of filters (or both). The learning rate can also play a part here, but is trickier to tune correctly.

What I came up with, that seemed to work reliably, is the following where I have increased the number of filters slightly and the number of iterations quite a bit. This isn't so much of an issue since the training data is so small, and still finishes rather quickly. With the nature of the signals in each class, the choice of a kernel size of 2 shouldn't be an issue (the one class has no deviation from 1, so the convolution across 2 features should be fine to differentiate them). Here is the code that seems to work for me (note: I have balanced the training data, though it doesn't make much of a difference):

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv1D, Dense, MaxPool1D, Flatten
import numpy as np

n_features = 5

model = Sequential()
model.add(
    Conv1D(
        filters=10,
        kernel_size=2,
        input_shape=(n_features, 1)
    )
)
model.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=1))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(
    loss='mae',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

print(model.summary())

# get some data
X = np.array(
    [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],
    dtype=np.float32
)
X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=2)

y = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])

# fit model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=1000)

predictions = model.predict(X)
Y_predict_classes = model.predict_classes(X)
```

I'd be interested in hearing from others as to what other optimizations and simplifications could be made to this network.

Answer (score 0):

Because 80% of your labels are "1", so the networks learns to always output "1" and this will easily obtain 80% accuracy. Your labels should be balanced in order for learning to work well.

Comment: I'm not sure this is true. I have been playing around with this code thinking the same, yet balancing the training data doesn't help. I admit there are other issues here, such as the limited number of training examples. However, with the examples of each of the 2 classes being identical one would think it should be a trivial problem.

Comment: @Fiver Yes I didn't notice that the training inputs have only two unique values, that definitely contributes.